# Websphere load balancer resides in webserver?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, dmz

In a clustered architecture where there are multiple app server(nodes), load balancing takes place at web-server level or somewhere else.

Is it possible that we can have load balancing among two web-servers?

Comment: Yes. Not sure why you would think that you could not.

Comment: if a request comes to web-server and then load balancing takes place. Then in case we have two web-servers, who will take care of delegating request to web-server1/web-server2? Because load balancing takes place after request is received by web-server.

Comment: It appears that you are assuming that websphere must be the front-end (there are reverse proxies which can take that role, it is also possible to install other webservers and use websphere as a loadbalanced backend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar thread from several years ago on developerworks-- WebSphere >‎ Forum: WebSphere Application Server >‎ Topic: Load Balancing Requests from WAS to Web servers :

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=19dd59d6-eb09-4c00-b7ae-0bcd6c8315f5

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is yes you can have multiple web-servers. It depends on the level of fail-over you want to support, but a pretty standard topology is using a load balancer (like F5) which then routes to a web server (IHS+WebSphere Plugin) which handles routing to back-end AppServer and ensures HTTP session affinity.

A lengthy, but detailed read, on how you might choose the right approach:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1010_pape/1010_pape.html